# Empty merge request

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a problem with a merge request. I work alone in a project so I only have my master branch. But someone ask me to review my code with a merge request. So I create a branch but it is the same with my master branch. So the merge request is empty.

How can I have all my files in the merge request to review and comment ?

Comment: The fact that your new branch name and your existing `master` branch name identify the same commit is not important. What matters is which commit they identify, what commits are in the upstream repository, and how you go about making the pull request. Include these details in your question so that someone can actually answer it.

Comment: All comits are from the master branch but I want to delete them all

Comment: You can't really *delete* a commit. You *can* stop using it: remember that Git *finds* a commit by its hash ID. Git often finds a commit's hash ID by looking at a branch name. Each branch name stores *one* hash ID, and that one hash ID is the one that Git finds using the name. But each commit usually also stores exactly one hash ID inside itself: that hash ID is the (single) *parent* of the commit, i.e., the commit that comes just before that commit. So if a branch name holds the ID of the *last* commit—and by definition, it does—then Git can find the *last* commit and work backwards.

Comment: Hence, if you want Git *not* to find some set of commits, simply tell Git to write some *other* commit's hash ID into that branch name, or delete that branch name entirely. That's all you have to do because that is all that Git itself does: read a name, find a commit, and then use that commit to find earlier commits.

Comment: When it comes to pull requests, the only thing that matters to GitHub (which is not Git!) is what commit hash ID you have GitHub find through a branch name (so here GitHub works the same way Git does). I imagine GitLab does the same thing, but every add-on to Git adds on their own special tricks, so that you'll use them and not their competition. As I don't have GitLab and have not used it, these are all comments, and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `git reflog` to see HEAD{n} before merge

If lets say commit before merge is HEAD@{2}

Then do

`git reset --hard HEAD@{2}` if you want reset to master branch and delete all changes made by merge

Comment: The two branches never merged. I create the new branch just after all my commits